# iOS: Reading contents of PDF File

Tags: ios, pdf

By going to the Quartz 2D programming guide and some of the post on SO I pieced together some code to read the contents of a PDF file. It's failing on the PDF Scanner part, I think. When I go to release the scanner the app crashes with this error:

```
avi(2282,0x3de7bb88) malloc: *** error for object 0x693f7c0: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
```

I am opening the PDF file through an email attachment. I know it's at least recognizing the file as I can get the page count. Could someone look at my code below and see where my error is happening? Thanks.

```
- (void) readPDFFile:(NSURL *)PDFURL {

    //make a pdf document and point it to the url of our pdf file
    CGPDFDocumentRef pdfDocument;
    pdfDocument = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)(PDFURL));

    //release the url
    CFRelease((__bridge CFTypeRef)(PDFURL));


    if (pdfDocument) {

        //get page count
        int pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages (pdfDocument);

        //
        if (pageCount > 0) {

            //set up operator table
            CGPDFOperatorTableRef pdfOpTable;
            pdfOpTable = CGPDFOperatorTableCreate();

            //call backs for Op Table
            CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (pdfOpTable, "MP", &op_MP);
            CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (pdfOpTable, "DP", &op_DP);
            CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (pdfOpTable, "BMC", &op_BMC);
            CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (pdfOpTable, "BDC", &op_BDC);
            CGPDFOperatorTableSetCallback (pdfOpTable, "EMC", &op_EMC);

            for(int i=0; i<pageCount; i++) {

                //set up
                CGPDFPageRef thisPage;
                CGPDFScannerRef pdfScanner;
                CGPDFContentStreamRef thisContentStream;

                //get the page
                thisPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage (pdfDocument, i + 1 );

                //get the page content stream
                thisContentStream = CGPDFContentStreamCreateWithPage (thisPage);

                //create a pdf scanner using our previously created table and callbacks
                pdfScanner = CGPDFScannerCreate (thisContentStream, pdfOpTable, NULL);

                //scan the pdf file
                CGPDFScannerScan (pdfScanner); //-->call backs happen here

                //release everything
                CGPDFPageRelease (thisPage);
                /*CGPDFScannerRelease (pdfScanner);
                CGPDFContentStreamRelease (thisContentStream);*/


            }
        }
    }

    //release the pdf document
    CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdfDocument);


}

static void op_MP (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {

    const char *name;

    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;

    NSLog(@"MP /%s\n", name);
}

static void op_DP (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    const char *name;
    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;
    NSLog(@"DP /%s\n", name);
}

static void op_BMC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    const char *name;
    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;
    NSLog(@"BMC /%s\n", name);
}

static void op_BDC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    const char *name;
    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;
    NSLog(@"BDC /%s\n", name);
}

static void op_EMC (CGPDFScannerRef s, void *info) {
    const char *name;
    if (!CGPDFScannerPopName(s, &name))
        return;
    NSLog(@"EMC /%s\n", name);
}
```

EDIT: PDFURL comes from this process: User opts to open PDF file attached to email with app. In AppDelegate.m:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
   /* NSLog(@"Open URL:\t%@\n"
          "From source:\t%@\n"
          "With annotation:%@",
          url, sourceApplication, annotation);*/

    NSMutableDictionary* userData = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

    [userData setObject:@"Read PDF" forKey:@"Action"];
    [userData setObject:url forKey:@"File Path"];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"theMessenger" object:self userInfo: userData];

    //NSString *filepath = [url path];
    //...
    return YES;
}
```

in viewcontroller.m

```
- (void) receiveNotification:(NSNotification* ) notification {
...
} else if ([strAction isEqualToString:@"Read PDF"]) {

            NSURL* documentURL = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"File Path"];
            [self readPDFFile:documentURL];

        }
...
```

EDIT: If I do not release this page app still crashes:

libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release:
0x3be89f20:  cmp    r0, #0
0x3be89f22:  it     eq
0x3be89f24:  bxeq   lr
0x3be89f26:  ldr    r1, [r0]
0x3be89f28:  movs   r2, #2
0x3be89f2a:  ldr    r1, [r1, #16]
0x3be89f2c:  bfi    r1, r2, #0, #2
0x3be89f30:  ldrb   r1, [r1]
0x3be89f32:  tst.w  r1, #2
0x3be89f36:  bne    0x3be89f3e                ; objc_release + 30
0x3be89f38:  movs   r1, #0
0x3be89f3a:  b.w    0x3be981c0                ; -[NSObject release]
0x3be89f3e:  movw   r1, #19326
0x3be89f42:  movt   r1, #507
0x3be89f46:  add    r1, pc
0x3be89f48:  ldr    r1, [r1]
0x3be89f4a:  b.w    0x3be875a0                ; objc_msgSend
0x3be89f4e:  nop

Comment: Where does the `PDFURL` come from? Are you sure it has to be released inside your method?

Comment: @Martin - see edits at bottom of OP

Comment: You should not release `PDFURL` because you don't own `documentURL` in the calling method.

Comment: That didn't make a difference. Does the NSURL get released through ARC then? My issue comes when I am within the document.

Comment: the simplified rule is: if you didn't allocate / create / copy stuff don't release. that goes for the pageRef and the url :)

Comment: Things you can/should do: Run "Product -> Analyze" (and fix all warnings!) - If that does not help: Set the "Enable Zombie Objects" option or run the app with Instruments (Zombie tool).

Answer (score 1):

dont release thisPage.. you get it via a GET call not a copy or a create method meaning you don't own it

--

dont release PDURL.. you get it from outside but you don't own it

--

do release the operatorTable .. you CREATE it

AND

dont reuse it for multiple scanners

Comment: if I put the code in a i>0 condition it doesn't crash. But I also don't get any data.